'RNDatePicker' could not be found. Expo 50.0.14 React Native
I am facing the issue with picker/date picker.
I am using expo 50.0.14
I must mention that this error did not show on expo 49.0.21 but when I ran eas build and install apk on my android device app crashes and report this RNDatePicker error.
I am not even sure what does RNDatePicker means in my case because I am using picker and datetime-picker as in my package.json but getting this error:


ERROR  Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNDatePicker' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes



my package.json


{
  "name": "rsrv",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --port 19000",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "expo": "^50.0.14",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "^12.9.3",
    "expo-checkbox": "^2.7.0",
    "expo-constants": "^15.4.5",
    "expo-device": "^5.9.3",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^12.7.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.10",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.30.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}



Is there any permanent solutions, ways to make sure my application will work when deployed on physical devices?
Thanks in advance for helping!
EDIT
Looks like using "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.1" insted of "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0" solved the issue. I also updated other packages as you can see below.
I will need to build expo apk and install it on real device to confirm the solution. Hope this helps!
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "expo": "~50.0.14",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.9.3",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.7.0",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.5",
    "expo-device": "~5.9.3",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.7.2",
    "expo-notifications": "^0.27.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.73.6",
    "react-native-credit-card-input": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0"
  },


I can confirm using "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.1" instead of "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0" solved the issue in my case.
